# Can't start using cygwin console

Tags: cygwin

I'm new to cygwin and faced with problem after installed it.
Starting cygwin i see console with:

```
/bin/sh: No such file or directory
```

i've installed it to:C:\app\cygwin 
version is: 1.7.14-1

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed by installing v 1.7.5-1 and then v 1.7.14-1